# Why is the HTML button not responding to JavaScript redirect?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am fairly new to Web development and I am struggling get a login form work with JavaScript. Basically, I am trying to hock it up to Firebase, but even before that; every time if hit the sign-in button it spits out the email and password in text on the browser URL and doesn't redirect, regardless where I am redirecting to.

I have tried to redirect to another HTML that I have in the same directory, I have tried Google's home page. Nothing works regardless of what I do with the JavaScript.

This is my HTML

**Note**: The CSS is not added so it will not get the look and feel.

```
<div class="login-form">
                                 <div class="form-help-text">Looking for the Advertiser Login? <a href="advertiser-Login.html">Click here</a></div>
                                <div class="login-form-container">
                                    <form name="loginForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>
                                        <div class="form-group" show-errors>
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email Address:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" ng-model="formData.username" required autofocus>
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group" show-errors>
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" ng-model="formData.password" required>
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>                                                
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <button id = "loginEmail" class = "btn btn-lg btn-block btn-wrapify-login">Sign In Email</button>
                                            <!--<button id = "login" class="btn btn-lg btn-wrapify-login btn-block">Sign In </button>-->
                                            <div class="member-login-container">
                                                Not a member yet? <a href="#">Sign Up!</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="divider"><img src="img/button-divider.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
                                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-fb-login btn-block" <i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sign In With Facebook</button>
                                            <div class="divider"></div>
                                            <div id="google-signin-button"></div>
                                            <p class="text-center m-t-sm"><a href"#"">Forgot Your Password?</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

This it the JavaScript. Everything seems to work fine when inspecting on Chrome JS Console, but I never redirect to the next page

```
const textEmail = document.getElementById("email");
const textPword = document.getElementById("password");
const btn = document.getElementById("loginEmail");
// const email = document.getElementById("signup");

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // Get email and passwrd
    const email = textEmail.value;
    const pword = textPword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pword);
    console.log("logging in ");
    promise.catch(function(error){
        console.log(error.message);
    });
    // console.log(promise);
    window.location = "post-login.html";
    //window.location.href = "post-login.html"; //just to see if it makes a difference
    //window.location = "http://www.google.com";//tried this as well
    //window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";//tried this as well

});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding `method=POST` to your `<form>`

Comment: `promise.then(function(error){
       window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"; 
});` , this might cancel the authentication, that is you will not be authenticated anymore

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like:`<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';" value="Redirect" />`

Answer (score 0):

Your JS runs when the submit button is clicked.

You set `location` to a new value, then the JS finishes and normal form submission takes over and the form is submitted.

Capture the event object and prevent the default behaviour of the button when the JS is successful:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
    ...
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```